# Pulling 1 item from a list in a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

So I have a dictionary with keys that contain lists of items.

```
some_dict= {
    'thing_one' : ['Test', '1', 'one', "uno"],
    'thing_two' : ['Scissors', 'Dos', 'two'],
          }
```

Now let's say I want to print "Test"

```
print (some_dict['thing_one'])
```

returns

```
'Test', '1', 'one', "uno"
```

So if I try to pull the first item...

```
print (some_dict['thing_one'[0]])
```

I get...

```
KeyError: 't'
```

Comment: Aside: `print (some_dict['thing_one'])` should print `['Test', '1', 'one', 'uno']` (with the brackets) so I'm skeptical that it does what you say. Even more technically, it doesn't *return* anything (`print` isn't a function in Python 2). It *outputs* the list representation. In Python 3 it would return `None`.

Answer (score 5):

Move the brackets:

```
print (some_dict['thing_one'][0])
```

This applies the `[0]` index to the result of the `some_dict['thing_one']` expression.

You were indexing the string `'thing_one'` instead and the first character of that string is `'t'`:

```
>>> 'thing_one'[0]
't'
```

and `'t'` is not a key in your `some_dict` dictionary.